# Simplifying Radical expressions

Tags: radicals

Simplify $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 1+\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}}+\cdots +\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{9}}$

Comment: The first term has $2$.

Comment: I editted it already sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})}=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$

Then $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 1+\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2+\sqrt3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3+\sqrt4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt8+\sqrt9}=$$
$$=\sqrt2-\sqrt1+\sqrt3-\sqrt2+\sqrt4-\sqrt3+...+\sqrt9-\sqrt8=\sqrt9-\sqrt1=3-1=2$$

Comment: The denominator is incorrect. It should be $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$ in the second radical.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:)**

Use $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}=-\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}$$ and make a telescopic expression.

Comment: Can you explain it further sir

Comment: Set $n=1, 2, \cdots,8$ and see what happen!